# How do you limit the number of people executing a PHP script at once? (Queue, 'spot' system)

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, file-upload, upload

I have an upload system ready, however I might be facing a very high load that may bring down our servers. The hosting provider limits the instances of a PHP script running at the same time to about 30. However, while people are uploading they often take longer than expected to finish the script and other people are given an "Internal Server Error" until a spot frees up.

My specific question is, is there a way to limit the number of people running the script at the same time? For example, a queueing system where only 29 people are uploading at the same time (server stays up) and other people can only start uploading when spots free up. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a value (ideally in Memcache, but MySQL works fine too) that says how many people are uploading. It starts at zero, then when someone starts uploading you increment it before starting to process the upload. When the upload has finished, decrement the counter again.

If the counter is above your threshold, stop people from accessing the uploader or give a friendly error message.

Alternatively, find a host with better systems. I hope this doesn't count as advertising, but [the host I use](http://www.tsohost.co.uk/) provides much, MUCH better systems, and almost certainly cheaper than whatever you're paying your current host.

Comment: I will have to try this and see how it goes. Would I just place the increment value at the start of the PHP script and the decrement value at the bottom? 

As for hosting, I agree. This host is only limited to 30 because it's shared hosting. As for the host you suggested, unfortunately 100GB is not sufficient disk space for my needs.

Comment: If you try this method, you will also need to run a CRON or similar to free the counter. This is because I can see a problem where users could do a half-upload and leave, not dropping your counter number.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure they havn't limited the number of apache processes or php processes? If they did there isn't much you can do but ask them to raise the limit. If it truely is a limit on the concurrent executions of a single PHP script then you could work around it as below...

Have lots of scripts that do the exact same thing. They can be symlinks to a single "control" script so that their content is always the same. Then choose one of the scripts at random when presenting the form.

Comment: It's configured into cPanel to be like that. There's a status indicator showing how many processes are running currently and if that goes over 30, the server goes down. It doesn't matter which scripts are running, as long as there are less than 30.